# Force Build Time Static Generation in Next.js 14.X

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, sanity

I have a blog built with Next.js 14.0.3 which calls a headless CMS API (Sanity) and I host it on Vercel. I've configured sanity to rebuild my site when I publish something new but I have run into issues with Vercel and their [Data Cache](https://vercel.com/docs/infrastructure/data-cache). My app rebuilds but requests to the Sanity API seem to be cached so that my new content does not show - I managed to fix this using `export const revalidate = 0;` to disable the cache but I think due to Incremental Static Generation this will mean my CMS API will be hit with every request which is unnecessary. Am I right in thinking this is what will happen due to the Incremental Static Generation?

Is there a way to force my pages to built statically at build time and opt out of incremental static generation? It doesn't seem all that useful in my case and I could be charged more for excess requests.

I've added "force-static"; to some pages but I'm really not sure if this fixes the issue as the documentation isn't clear.

Alternatively is there a way to request Vercel clears the cache for a site that I can incorporate into a build process?

Comment: have the same question! did you end up figuring it out? been searching for over 2 hours. its pretty crazy that there isn't any proper documentation for this at all.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I'm afraid what I did here "force-static" in a few places was all I could do! It is absolutely crazy that Vercel hasn't written better documentation for this. It hardly matters on my site but this is a big deal for sites with much larger traffic numbers

Comment: definitely! we use graphql, so every request is a post request. we ended up going with https://github.com/alfonsusac/nextjs-better-unstable-cache, along with `revalidate` flags, which helped us get the achieved goal of "ISG"